# Prime number calculator functions, why is one correct and the other incorrect?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've seen some similar codes here on stack overflow but none had my same question.
basically, my question is why when I tried to check the inequality (!=) in the for loop it didn't work. But when I tried using the equality (==) it worked fine?

so this code returns True always:

```
def is_prime(x):
  if x == 2:
    return True
  else:
    for i in range(2, x):
        if x > 2:
            if x % i != 0:
                return True
    return False
```

while this code is works fine:

```
def is_prime(x):
  if x < 2:
    return False
  if x == 2:
    return True
  else:
    for i in range(2, x):
        if x > 2:
            if x % i == 0:
                return False
    return True
```

Comment: When a function returns anything the loop immediately stops executing.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the programs in a debugger? Or have you at least tried adding print statements to trace where you are in the function?

Comment: excuse my incompetence but I'm fairly new to programming, What do you mean "stepping the programs in a debugger"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second function is correct because it returns `False` if in any loop `x % i == 0`. Otherwise, it returns `True`. This is the definition of a prime number.

Your first function is incorrect because it returns `True` if in any loop `x % i != 0`. Otherwise, it returns `False`. The problem with this is that for *all* integers *k* > 2 there exists an integer *i* in range [2, *k*) such that *k* % *i* does not equal 0. Trivially, you can set *i* = *k* - 1. So the function will always return `True`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you so much.